# sql comparing the value on the same table

Tags: sql

Can i compare the value on the table with the same value on sql without creating the new table
[sql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBERA.png)
selisih means difference between the value and nilai means value

```
Create table tblData(
  nourut int,
  nama varchar(50),
  nilai int
);
Create table tblData1(
  nourut int,
  nama varchar(50),
  nilai int
);
insert into tblData values
(1,"Yuanita Prabandini Soesilo",85),
(2,"Marco Anthonius Pareira",80),
(3,"William Jaya Dwipangga",95);
insert into tblData1 values
(1,"Yuanita Prabandini Soesilo",85),
(2,"Marco Anthonius Pareira",80),
(3,"William Jaya Dwipangga",95);
select tblData.nama as namamhs,
tblData.nilai,
tblData1.nama,
tblData1.nilai,
case
when(tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai<0)
then (tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai)*-1
when(tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai>=0)
then (tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai)
end as selisih
from tblData,tblData1
where tblData1.nama<>tblData.nama
order by tblData1.nama DESC;
```

I create two tblData in order to compare which is not efficient any other way to compare the value on the same table without creating the new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one table is needed, in the FROM clause you give each table an Alias so you can bring the table into your query twice:

```
select t1.nama as namamhs,
t1.nilai,
t2.nama,
t2.nilai,
case
when(t1.nilai-t2.nilai<0)
then (t1.nilai-t2.nilai)*-1
when(t1.nilai-t2.nilai>=0)
then (t1.nilai-t2.nilai)
end as selisih
from tblData as t1, tblData as t2
where t1.nama<>t2.nama
order by t2.nama DESC;
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much for giving  the solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) a table to itself by using an [`ALIAS`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php).

```
SELECT
  d1.nama as namamhs,
  d1.nilai,
  d2.nama,
  d2.nilai,
  CASE
    WHEN (d1.nilai - d2.nilai < 0)
      THEN (d1.nilai - d2.nilai) * -1
    WHEN (d1.nilai - d2.nilai >= 0)
      THEN (d1.nilai - d2.nilai)
  END AS selisih
FROM tblData d1
INNER JOIN tblData d2 ON d1.nama <> d2.nama
ORDER BY d2.nama DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select 
  a.nama,
  a.nilai,
  b.nama,
  b.nilai,
  abs(a.nilai-b.nilai) 
from tbldata as a ,tbldata as b
where a.nama<>b.nama
order by b.nama desc
```